# Querying table with multiple items inside same column (and ignore redundant)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to find a clever way to solve a issue using SQL queries... so I hope some of you guys help me how to figure out.

I receive in a stored a defined as parameter a "table type" that could contain something like this:

```
    AA

    BB|AA

    AA|BB|CC

    CC

    DD
```

This a raw selection of product codes. And some rows contain multiple codes in same column.

So, in order to execute further steps, this procedure need to perform some cleaning to to filter the redundant codes or code bundles that could be contained in other bigger bundles.

The excepted result should be something like this:

```
    AA|BB|CC

    DD
```

(because both AA and AA|BB are already contained in AA|BB|CC ... like DD is not is no part of other)

This should be faster for large lists, so I believe that using only queries would be faster, but it's a little bit out of my knowledge, specially when possible multiple items in the same column using a separator...

Codes could be for 2 to 6 letters, and one ore different codes could be in same line with a separator.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: What query/queries have you tried?

Comment: You need provide bigger sample and more detail description of what redundant mean.

Comment: Is it `BB|AA` or `AA|BB` in your sample data??

Comment: JNevill, Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.2000.8 (X64)   Feb 20 2014 20:04:26   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (Hypervisor)

Comment: Mahmoud Gamal, BB|AA and AA|BB should be considered the same bundle of two codes.  If both present.. only one should be returned.

My problem is that "table type" only contains a varchar column that can contain one-multiple codes with a separator. Codes can have several characters ... that's why I'm finding this tricky! :)

(i removed the column numbers in example so not be confused with  id)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why not just to split everything to separate rows and use distinct?

If this:

```
AA
BB|AA
AA|BB|CC
```

Is the same thing as this:

```
AA|BB|CC
```

Then it must be the same thing as this:

```
AA
BB
CC
```

So just use a string split function to split the data into rows, for example [DelimitedSplit8k](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/) by Jeff Moden.

Comment: It's more tricky than that... :)


AA is a single product code.

AA|BB|CC is a group of 3 product codes. one of them is AA.

AA|BB|CC should be considered the same as AA|CC|BB as they contain the same codes.


If the procedure receives a line with codes already contained in a group... they should be ignored. 

The intention is to clear all codes or smaller groups of codes that are contained in larger groups.

Thank you, JamesZ!

Comment: Ok, so you need to remove such rows where all the items exist in one of the other rows? I'd still use the split, but assign each original row a number, and then check other groups if they contain all the items in the group to be checked